# Hotstring not caputring when I sendInput from ahk script

Tags: autohotkey

I am using Autohotkey script for this purpose. I want to capture hotstring while I am sending input from other ahk script.
    One script having all hotstring such as

```
:*:qwe:: 123456
:*:asd:: 789456
```

(Its running in background)

when I send input from other script like
here is the code

```
^a::
Input, Variable, , {Enter}
value := substring(Variable,1,3)
sendInput, %Value%
return
```

but it not capturing.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [SendLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm)

Script 1:

```
; Does not work with * auto replace feature.
::qwe:: 123456
::asd:: 789456
```

Script 2:

```
^a::
    Sendlevel, 1
    Input, Variable, , {Enter}
    value := substring(Variable,1,3)
    sendInput, %Value%{space}
return
```